# Setting UserControl properties dynamcally on Aspx page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Im making a generic modal usercontrol that i can call on different Aspx pages and set the text via parameter. First i created 2 properties on the Codebehind of my UserControl

```
    public partial class _modalGenerica : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Than i created the modal button on my ascx and tried to access the properties

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="_modalGenerica.ascx.cs" Inherits="GS1.CNP.WEBUI.views.backoffice.areaEstatica.formularioProduto._modalGenerica" %>






<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="<%this.Title%>" data-content="<%this.Body%>"> Click to toggle popover</button>
```

And lastly i call the UC on the the aspx page with this line

```
<partial:_modalGenerica runat="server" id="_modalGenerica" Body="Hhahaha" Title="Teste" />
```

The aspx page is not loading after i created the button modal, any ideas? or better solutions for this?

Comment: To start, your button is HTML, it needs to be an ASP.NET control.

Comment: Not really, worked this way, only had to change title="<%this.Title%> to  title="<=Title>"